# SOLR 7.5 crashes

Tags: java, solr, java-9, solr7

I'm rebuilding my index from a Wordpress plugin, this uses the Parametric solr-php-client. Frequently, when updating the index, SOLR crashes with an error message as below. Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with debugging SOLR/Java applications. So far, what I've tried was to increase the Java stack sie (-Xss256k -> -Xss1M in JVM startup), it seemed to me that this was too low on 64bit Java 9 (OpenJDK). Any help or clues are much appreciated.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007fa5c5eb5a19, pid=53143, tid=53258
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, concurrent mark sweep gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# J 10526 C2 org.apache.lucene.util.packed.DeltaPackedLongValues$Builder.pack([JIIF)V (73 bytes) @ 0x00007fa5c5eb5a19 [0x00007fa5c5eb5900+0x0000000000000119]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P" (or dumping to /opt/solr-7.5.0/server/core.53143)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /opt/solr-7.5.0/server/hs_err_pid53143.log
Compiled method (c2)  384322 10526       4       org.apache.lucene.util.packed.DeltaPackedLongValues$Builder::pack (73 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x00007fa5c5eb5790,0x00007fa5c5eb5ec8] = 1848
 relocation     [0x00007fa5c5eb58d0,0x00007fa5c5eb5900] = 48
 main code      [0x00007fa5c5eb5900,0x00007fa5c5eb5d20] = 1056
 stub code      [0x00007fa5c5eb5d20,0x00007fa5c5eb5d48] = 40
 oops           [0x00007fa5c5eb5d48,0x00007fa5c5eb5d50] = 8
 metadata       [0x00007fa5c5eb5d50,0x00007fa5c5eb5d58] = 8
 scopes data    [0x00007fa5c5eb5d58,0x00007fa5c5eb5e00] = 168
 scopes pcs     [0x00007fa5c5eb5e00,0x00007fa5c5eb5e90] = 144
 dependencies   [0x00007fa5c5eb5e90,0x00007fa5c5eb5e98] = 8
 handler table  [0x00007fa5c5eb5e98,0x00007fa5c5eb5eb0] = 24
 nul chk table  [0x00007fa5c5eb5eb0,0x00007fa5c5eb5ec8] = 24
Could not load hsdis-amd64.so; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a problem writing the Java error messages to the solr.log file. I've reinstalled openjdk-9 and now SOLR doesn't crash and I get a proper error message in my solr.log file.